# no loader is there if document rendering is in progress @cyntler/react-doc-viewer reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-doc-viewer

I have list of documents to load and in react on click of row item i am showing doc viewer , i have urls from local server that are working fine if i am hitting it from browser like this

```
http://localhost:8085/api/enquiries/docs/preview?key=docs/ENQ_37/6gE6WoUL.jpg
```

On clicking of document previewer is not showing any loader but just the blank page, and randomly it shows files preview, sometimes work sometimes not

```
const handleDocClick = (doc) => {
    console.log("handleDocClick ~ doc:", doc);
    setSelecetdDoc(doc);
  };

<Grid container style={{ height: '800px' }}>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={4} style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <DocList docs={docs} handleClick={handleDocClick} style={{ height: "100%" }} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} md={8} style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <DocPreview doc={selectedDoc} />
      </Grid>
    </Grid >
```

and the DocPreview

```
export default function DocPreview({ doc }) {
  const [selectedDoc, setSelecetdDoc] = useState(doc);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (doc) {
      console.log("yes working")
      setSelecetdDoc(doc);
    }
  }, [doc])
  return (
    <DocViewer prefetchMethod="GET" style={{ borderRadius: "10px", height: "100%" }}
      documents={[{ fileType: selectedDoc?.fileType, fileName: selectedDoc?.name, uri: selectedDoc?.uri }]}
      pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers} />
  )
}

DocPreview.propTypes = {
  doc: PropTypes.shape({
    uri: PropTypes.string,
    fileType: PropTypes.string,
    fileName: PropTypes.string,
  })
```

**Update1**

In list i have 3 files 2 images and one is pdf. First time everything works fine, click on item this is not previewed yet will work fine.

Now if everything is clicked once and last was image loaded then and now i click on image item, no preview api call in network and no image preview will be loaded, now if i click on pdf item , network call will be there and pdf preview will work, and now click on any image item, network call will be there and image will be loaded, again click on other image item then no network call and image preview too will not be loaded.

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed all the docs

```
  <Grid item xs={12} md={8} style={{ height: "100%" }}>
        <DocPreview doc={selectedDoc} docs={docs.data?.map((doc) => { return { fileType: doc?.fileType, fileName: doc?.name, uri: doc?.uri } })} />
      </Grid>
```

and in the doc preview used `activeDocument` prop

```
export default function DocPreview({ doc, docs = [] }) {

  return (
    <DocViewer prefetchMethod="GET" style={{ borderRadius: "10px", height: "100%" }}
      documents={docs}
      activeDocument={{ fileType: doc?.fileType, fileName: doc?.name, uri: doc?.uri }}
      pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a custom loader in the package [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@cyntler/react-doc-viewer#overriding-loading-renderer)

```
const MyLoadingRenderer = ({ document, fileName }) => {
  const fileText = fileName || document?.fileType || "";

  if (fileText) {
    return <div>Loading Renderer ({fileText})...</div>;
  }

  return <div>Loading Renderer...</div>;
};

<DocViewer
  pluginRenderers={DocViewerRenderers}
  documents={
    {
      // ...
    }
  }
  config={{
    loadingRenderer: {
      overrideComponent: MyLoadingRenderer,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: will this solve not showing the previw on change of document?

Comment: Not sure but mostly probably it will again switch to loader as document is changed.

Comment: i got the issue can you check the question update and loader is not working